# confused about __init__ method inside of def __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

In the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

    class CardShuffling(tk.Tk):
        background_colour = '#D3D3D3'
        deck_size = 52

        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self) # What does this do?
```

I am confused about the purpose of the last line.. an instance of CardShuffling inherits from `tk.Tk`, doesn't the last line just repeat what is already taken care of by `CardShuffling(tk.Tk)` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CardShuffling(tk.Tk)` only makes the class `CardShuffling` a child of `tk.Tk`. your new class inherits all the methods of this class.

but if you create a new object you still have to call the constructor of that base class (with the new object as argument). imagine there is a line `self.a = 0` in the constructor of the parent class. your child class has to run this line when you initialize a new instance; `CardShuffling(tk.Tk)` can not do that for you; you need to run `__init__` of the parent class.

the usual way to do that in python 3 is

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

which is the same in this case as

```
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

maybe this [article on inheritance](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php) helps and there is even a [book chapter](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/inheritance-python) freely available.

Comment: I've read through the article but still slightly confused. CardShuffling is a child of tk.Tk, therefore it has all methods of tk.Tk - but we still need to explicitly state that in the constructor of the child class? could you flesh out the `self.a = 0` comment? Why doesn't CardShuffling(tk.Tk) run that line from the parent constructor if it inherits everything from the parent constructor..

Comment: because `self` does not exist at the time you are defining your class. you only get an instance (something that has a `self`) when you state: `cs = CardShuffling()`. now `cs` is an instance. only now you could attach a member like `self.a` (which would then translate to `cs.a`) to that instance.