# imported python file wont return variable from class to original file

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I want the code to import a python file which displays a tkinter window with 2 buttons. Depending on which button the user presses it runs a function which should return a certain string to the original python file. Ive done this before with returning the contents of an entry box to the original file, but for this task i havent got a clue as the code makes sense to me and no error is produced?

Original python code:

```
def menu():
    import Menu_window
    Login_or_create= Menu_window.start()
    print(Login_or_create)

    if Login_or_create == "Login":
        print("Logged in")

    if Login_or_create == "Create":
        print("Creating user")
```

Imported file named Menu_Window.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Menu_window():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("Menu")

        bottom_frame=LabelFrame(self.window)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=2)

        Login= Label(text = "Hello, Please login or create an account to play!")
        Login.grid(row=0)

        ttk.Button(bottom_frame,text = 'Login',command = returN()).grid(row=0)
        ttk.Button(bottom_frame,text = 'Create account',command = returN2()).grid(row=0,column=1)

def returN():
    return "Login"

def returN2():
    return "Create"

def start():
    window=Tk()
    Login_or_Create=Menu_window(window)
    window.mainloop()
    window.destory()
```

Comment: `returN()` and `returN2()` do nothing here. `window.destory()` also does nothing here. Your button commands should save a reference to a function rather than call the function like this: `command = returN` and `command = returN2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 major flaws in your code.

1. `Login_or_create = Menu_window.start()` will always be `None` here. This is not being assigned a value from the return commands on your buttons.
2. When a button calls a function and you try to return something the button simply ignores that return value. It will never be assigned to your variable where you called the `Menu_window.Start()`.
3. In order to interact between classes you need to pass some class attribute or the class itself to the other. So in this case I am passing `Menu()` to `MenuWindow()` in order to be able to call a method to check what button was pressed.

I have edited your code to more closely follow PEP8 style guidelines. I have also converted your `Menu_window` class to inherit from tkinter tk for ease of use.

Renamed file name to follow class name.

Starting `py` file code:

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        import MenuWindow
        MenuWindow.start(self)

    def check_tracker(self, tracker):
        if tracker == "Login":
            print("Logged in")

        if tracker == "Create":
            print("Creating user")

Menu()
```

MenuWindow.py file:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MenuWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Menu")
        self.controller = controller
        bottom_frame= tk.LabelFrame(self)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=2)
        tk.Label(text = "Hello, Please login or create an account to play!").grid(row=0)
        ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Login', command=self.return_n).grid(row=1)
        ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Create account', command=self.return_n2).grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.mainloop()

    def return_n(self):
        self.controller.check_tracker("Login")

    def return_n2(self):
        self.controller.check_tracker("Create")

def start(x):
    MenuWindow(x)
```

Resulting in a window that depending on what button was pressed it will print to console from the Starting `py` file code:

[image]

Comment: What does the line tk.TK.__init__(self) actually do?

Comment: @peterwelsh There is a post here: [confused about __init__ method inside of def __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777323/confused-about-init-method-inside-of-def-init) and there is good documentation on its use here: [Inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php). To sum it up the line `tk.Tk.__init__(self)` is used to initialize all the base attributes/methods of the inherited class. So because I am creating a class that inherits from `Tk` I use `tk.Tk.__init__(self)` so that my custom `Tk` class has all the features of the built in `Tk` class.

Comment: I think i get it, but how would i go about closing this interface now that its not like declared as a window if that makes sense? because usually i use self.window.destroy().

Comment: Do `self.destroy()`.